# React.JS build works in dev server but not in AWS Amplify when anything changes in package.json

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, jsx, aws-amplify

I am a little bit perplexed here as I attempt to launch my first react project online.
I'm using AWS Amplify, I have connected my github repo, and have everything linked together, from VS Code I can push to my github, which then after a minute or so displays the changes inside of my AWS Amplify website, so I believe I have the vscode - GH - amplify pipeline operating properly...
I initialized a base react app, on the AWS site and it works as expected,
The dev server on localhost displays the same spinning logo and
**Edit src/App.js and save to reload**
I then added some extra random text as a test, within the app.js,
It added my hello world test text in the localhost. I push it to GH, it then appears exactly the same on my Amplify site as it does on dev server. the same react initial page but now both have the test text. I then delete all the components of the app.js
add a simple header nav bar, update package.json to include a couple dependencies (chakra-ui) and then the whole thing breaks.
I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but do I need to do anything outside of vs code, in order to have the package.json updates not ruin the compiling?

In VS Code i need to `npm install packages` do I need to do this somewhere inside AWS Amplify?

**here is the json that works fine**

```
{
  "name": "react-amplify-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I then try to add the JSON file from my full react project where i made a decently involved (for me anyway) website.
**Here is the updated JSON that makes it not work anymore**

```
{
  "homepage": "https://avarga1.github.io/My-Portfolio/",
  "name": "myreactportfolio11",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/core": "^0.8.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "iframe-resizer": "^4.2.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-s3": "^1.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "scripts": "^0.1.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

What am I missing???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does it break on build? Front-end or the back-end?